# State object cannot re assign by payload objects in mutations

Tags: vuex

I have this state object, with default values

```
state() {
return {
  projects: [
    { code: "01", name: "test" },
    { code: "01", name: "test" },
    { code: "01", name: "test" },
  ],
 };
},
```

and I'm trying to replace it with payload that came from actions,

```
mutations: {
 setProject(state,payload) {
  state.projects = payload;
 }
},
```

The problem is it doesn't replace the state.projects object when im trying to use console.log
i am using vuex 3.6.2 my payload is like this

```
[
 { code: "01", name: "Picture" },
 { code: "02", name: "Perfect" },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try state being an object not a function. E.g.

```
const state = {
  projects: [
    { code: "01", name: "test" },
    { code: "01", name: "test" },
    { code: "01", name: "test" },
  ],
}
```